# CakePHP store parameters to the paginator settings

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3, cakephp-2.1

I have a function that filters my paginator like this:

```
    public function indextipo() {
    $this->CabAsiento->recursive = 0;
    $tipo = $this->request->data['tipo'];       
    $fecha = $this->request->data['fecha_desde'];
    $this->Paginator->settings=array(
        'paramType' => 'querystring',               
         'limit'=> 1,
         'conditions' => array('CabAsiento.tipo_doc' => $tipo, 'MONTH(CabAsiento.fecha)' => $fecha),
         'order' => array('CabAsiento.id_numero' => 'ASC')
    );
    $this->set('cabAsientos', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    $this->layout = 'ingresos';         
}
```

it have the .ctp.

it works and display the filter data, but when I try to next the other page gives me:

> Undefined index: tipo [APP\Controller\CabAsientosController.php, line 35]
>
> Undefined index: fecha_desde [APP\Controller\CabAsientosController.php, line 36]

cause the parameters get lost.
How can I keep or store thos parameters sends by a form search:

```
            <div class="portlet-body">
            <?php echo $this->Form->create(false, array('action' => 'indextipo','id' => 'form-login1')); ?> 
            <fieldset>
            <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('fecha_desde', array('id'=>'fecha_desde1', 'type' => 'date','dateFormat' => 'M','class' => 'span3'));
                $arrCategory=array("ing"=>"Ingreso","egre"=>"Egreso","trasp"=>"Trapaso");
                echo $this->form->input('tipo',array('type' => 'select','options'=> $arrCategory)); 
            ?>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->button("<i class='icon-plus'></i> Buscar", array('type' => 'submit','id' => 'submit_id', 'class' => 'btn green', 'escape' => false, 'aria-hidden'=>"true"));
            echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>      
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be setup using the [Search Plugin](https://github.com/CakeDC/search).

Your controller should look something like:

```
class ArticlesController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Search.Prg'
    );

    public function find() {
        $this->Prg->commonProcess();
        $this->Paginator->settings['conditions'] = $this->Article->parseCriteria($this->Prg->parsedParams());
        $this->set('articles', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before accessing those data, you have to check their existence.

```
public function indextipo() {
    $settings = array(
        'paramType' => 'querystring',
        'limit' => 1,
        'order' => array('CabAsiento.id_numero' => 'ASC')
    );
    //Check if data are submited
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $tipo = $this->request->data('tipo');
        $fecha = $this->request->data('fecha_desde');
        $settings['conditions'] = array('CabAsiento.tipo_doc' => $tipo, 'MONTH(CabAsiento.fecha)' => $fecha);
    }

    $this->CabAsiento->recursive = 0;
    $this->Paginator->settings = $settings;
    $this->set('cabAsientos', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    $this->layout = 'ingresos';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after a several of information a did it:

```
if(isset($this->request->data['tipo']) && isset($this->request->data['fecha_desde']) && isset($this->request->data['numero']))
    {
        $this->Session->write('tipo', $this->request->data['tipo']);    
        $this->Session->write('fech', $this->request->data['fecha_desde']); 
        $this->Session->write('num', $this->request->data['numero']);   
    }

    $tipo = $this->Session->read('tipo');   
    $fecha = $this->Session->read('fech');
```

so I'm using session data to keep my search parameters stored and if im going to change page or another type of search this data will be keeped.